# How to import character package in Unity

Tags: unity, first-person-shooter, importing

I recently made a game in Unity 3D and I tried to import the FPS Controller package as the tutorial I was following said, but when I clicked Assets/Import Package the only thing I saw was a button saying 'Custom Package'

[image]

How do I get the character option when I click 'Import Package'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you installed Unity, you might have skipped installing the Standard Assets package. [You can download it for free from the Unity Asset Store here](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-32351).

Comment: I downloaded them and pressed import, but when it's done, I click 'import packages' and the only option still is custom package.

Comment: Click custom package and then select the Standard Assets package you downloaded.

Comment: When I go into "Characters" there aren't any accessible files.